# What's the pythonic way to integrate a function that returns an array (using scipy quad)?

Tags: python, arrays, scipy

I have a function that returns an array:

```
def fun(x,a):
    return [a*x,a*x**2]
```

and I want to integrate it (using scipy `quad`):

```
def integrate(a):
    return quad(fun[0],0,1,args=a)
print integrate(1)
```

This gives `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`.
What's the right, pythonic way to do this?

Comment: So you want to integrate over `ax`?

Comment: `fun[0]` is trying to subscript the function. Did you want to subscript the results of the function? In that case the syntax is `fun(param1, param2)[0]`

Comment: @tzaman: yes, integrate over the first (or any other) array element

Comment: @RobertB: 'quad(fun(x,a)[0],0,1,args=a)' gives 'NameError: global name 'x' is not defined'

Comment: Looking at 'quad', the first param is a function. So `fun` is your funciton, not `fun[0]`.  Also, do not call the second function "int" since that clobbers the standard python "int" type in your namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a wrapper function around `fun` to select an element of the array. For example, the following will integrate the first element of the array.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

# The function you want to integrate
def fun(x, a):
    return np.asarray([a * x, a * x * x])

# The wrapper function
def wrapper(x, a, index):
    return fun(x, a)[index]

# The integration
quad(wrapper, 0, 1, args=(1, 0))
```

Following @RobertB's suggestion, you should avoid defining a function `int` because it messes with the builtin names.

Comment: I think 'wrapper' is probably the wrong term, but the solution is valid enough

Comment: @Stick, what would you suggest as an alternative? Happy to make changes.

Comment: imho - It's just a function that calls another function. A wrapper would suggest a situation where you can use the `@my_func` syntax, or make use of an enclosure or something, right?

Comment: That's part of it, but you couldn't use a decorator in your example (which is part of the reason I don't know about calling it a "wrapper function", it's not wrapping anything). It really doesn't change the validity of the answer, so it probably just doesn't matter

Answer (score 3):

Your function returns an array, `integrate.quad` needs a float to integrate. So you want to give it a function that returns one of the elements from your array instead of the function itself. You can do that via a quick `lambda`:

```
def integrate(a, index=0)
    return quad(lambda x,y: fun(x, y)[index], 0, 1, args=a)
```

Comment: In this answer, I would not encourage the OP to define a function called 'int' since that will clobber the 'int' type. I know that it is what the OP did, but in your answer, perhaps you could use a different name?